# Stop triggering PopOver when title is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website. You can preview the page in question here: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/lobby.html (don't mind the sounds, they will not autoplay and there will be an option to play/mute them in the future).

I am using [mapify.js](https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify) for this project.

I want to enable PopOvers for the plaques near the doors that indicate the room's name.

I managed to activate the PopOvers but the problem is that I can't control the objects for which I want them to appear.

I don't want a PopOver when a someone hovers over other objects than those plaques.

Since the text in the PopOver is placed inside the `title` of the area I figured that checking if the `title` is empty to not trigger the PopOver.

Here is the code:

```
    $("img[usemap]").mapify({
    popOver: {
        content: function(zone){ 
                return "<strong>"+zone.attr("data-title")+"</strong>";
        },
        delay: 0.7,
        margin: "15px",
        height: "60px",
        width: "150px"
    }
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<area data-group-id="group-2"  alt="f01_r01" title="Secretariat"  shape="poly" coords="375,391,375,450,381,452,444,452,446,446,446,399,443,394,382,390" nohref  alt="" title="Secretariat" data-hover-class="custom-hover-1"/>
```

I looked on SO and I tried adding some conditions but it didn't end well.

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use a custom popover class for the areas you don't want a popover for, with a `display: none !important` style.

```
<area data-pop-over-class="hidden" href="#" shape="poly" coords="..." />

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Edit**

If you're open to modifying the original source, on line 445, you could change the following block:
https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify/blob/master/src/mapify.js#L445

```
Mapify.prototype._renderPopOver = function (zone) {
    // Ignore zones with `data-popover-disabled`
    if ($(zone)[0].hasAttribute('data-popover-disabled') return;

    if (!this.isCustomPopOver) {
        this._renderDefaultPopOver(zone);
    } else {
        this._renderCustomPopOver(zone);
    }
};
```

Then add `data-popover-disabled` to the zones you don't want a popover to display.

**Edit 2**

For your specified, minified version.

Find:

```
prototype._renderPopOver=function(a){this.isCustomPopOver?this._renderCustomPopOver(a):this._renderDefaultPopOver(a)}
```

Replace:

```
prototype._renderPopOver=function(a){if(a.hasAttribute('data-popover-disabled'))return;this.isCustomPopOver?this._renderCustomPopOver(a):this._renderDefaultPopOver(a)}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like the smart choice. Applied what you said but I get some weird behaviour. On first look it works but after staying on the page for some time and moving the mouse over the clickable items you'll notice that the PopOvers appear all over the place.

Comment: I can't see another way to do it without modifying the original source. Is that an option?

Comment: It wouldn't be but unfortunately I lack the skills to achieve this.

Comment: @SporeDev - I've edited my answer. The change is untested, but I think it should work.

Comment: Do you mean like this? data-ignore="true" ?

Comment: It doesnt need the `="true"` value. The selector will simply look for the existence of the attribute.

Comment: That seems to disable the area completely. Can't click on it anymore and it doesn't highlight.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the implication of the change. One more try. See edit above.

Comment: Hmm... it's weird that I don't have that code in my project. The version that I downloaded from GitHub seems to be a little different. Maybe it was updated. Here is mine: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/js/jquery.mapify.js It's minified but for some reason I can't seem to find the code that you're mentioning using Ctrl + F (tried searching for short bits of the code, not the whole thing).

Comment: You're using the minified source code. You'd need to get the unminified version, make the change and then reminify it. How did you make the last change if your source is minified?

Comment: It is a different version. I've added `find` and `replace` values. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for having the patience to help me! It works now!